# Python minimizer

Tags: python, 3d, lmfit

I am trying to fit a 3D line on a cloud of points. I am using a minimzer from lmfit.
I define the line-point distance as **np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p-v0,v1-v0))/np.linalg.norm(v1-v0)** (method 2 from http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/Point_to_line.htm). The problem is I am not sure the minimer does a good job. I am using the least square method, and the fit is not correct for lower number of points.

In fact, **np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p-v0,v1-v0))** seems to do a better job. If I understand it correctly, this would minimize the parallelogram area and not point-line distance.

Question: is there a better algo then least squares to minimize distances? is there a better library than lmfit? why would the second equation give better results, its just division by a scalar?

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, 
report_fit,fit_report, Minimizer, printfuncs
import numpy as np

params = Parameters()
params.add('x0',   value= 129)
params.add('x1',   value= -0.5)
params.add('y0',   value= 129)
params.add('y1',   value= -0.5)


def fun(params,x,y,z):
    x0 = params['x0'].value; x1 = params['x1'].value; y0 = 
params['y0'].value; y1 = params['y1'].value
    distance = []

    v0 = np.array([x0, y0, 0])
    v1 = np.array([x0+x1, y0+y1, 1])

    for point in range(len(x)):
        p = np.array([x[point], y[point], z[point]])
        distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p-v0,v1-v0))/np.linalg.norm(v1-v0))
    return distance

result = minimize(fun, params,args=(x,y,z))
print(fit_report(result))
```

---

Using plotly I can see the quality of the fit:[np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p-v0,v1-v0))/np.linalg.norm(v1-v0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlMIQ.png) vs [np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p-v0,v1-v0))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3QwD.png)

Comment: *"the fit is not correct for lower number of points."* - how do you know it's not correct?

Comment: I use plotly to see in 3D how the line fits to the points. Also, I know the correct angle the cloud has (0deg).
I get better results when removing np.linalg.norm(v1-v0).
If there are only 2 points I want the line to pass through them, and it does not.